# How I can send credentials to Core J2EE Patterns DAO

Tags: jakarta-ee, dao, factory-pattern

How I can send credentials in Core J2EE Patterns - Data Access Object?
I get model from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html

They offer this example to use

```
// create the required DAO Factory
DAOFactory cloudscapeFactory = DAOFactory.getDAOFactory(DAOFactory.DAOCLOUDSCAPE);

// Create a DAO
CustomerDAO custDAO = cloudscapeFactory.getCustomerDAO();

// create a new customer
int newCustNo = custDAO.insertCustomer(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is encrypt your password on controller servlet and send to DOM to save,
this would be the two way, at the time of login you need to decrypt it to authenticate.

Another way is use hashing, generate the hashvalue using some algorithm, and store the hash value in DB, you do the same hashing process again and match the hash value to authenticate.